# Why King was needed as a decoy to grab the attention of elder centipede?

Tags: one-punch-man

For grabbing the attention of elder centipede,

> and killing him, King was need as a decoy for Saitama to kill him.

Why King was needed as a decoy to grab the attention of elder centipede?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it was not King himself that was needed. In **Chapter 82**, you'll read the following dialogue:

> They say Centichoro cooperates with the Monster Association **so he can get revenge against Blast**...

Remember that it was not King himself that made Centichoro go after him but rather, *it was after he mentioned Blast*. King said that he brought Blast with him and after taunting Centichoro that he was too afraid to face Blast, Centichoro, presumably angered, went after him, thinking Blast was with him.

To conclude, *King himself was not specifically needed for the task*. It was his lie that Blast was there that distracted Centichoro since *Centichoro apparently wants to get revenge upon Blast*. Centichoro probably would not have wanted to miss the chance to get even so after hearing that Blast was there, he charged towards him. Saitama used Centichoro's hatred towards Blast against him, resulting to his defeat.

Comment: yeah, but couldnt just be Saitama the one who claimed to bring Blast with him? Was it because King is better known as a hero or something?

Comment: @Pablo Yeah, you have a point there. King was well known not just among heroes but monsters, too. If it was Saitama, then Centichoro would probably just ignore him, an unknown hero, thinking he's bluffing or he's just small fry. Then again, it's also possible he'd still believe Saitama. Remember, he wants to get revenge upon Blast and provoking him by saying that Blast was there, regardless of who the person is, would probably elicit the same reaction.